# C++ vtable query

Tags: c++

I have a query in regard to the explaination provided here http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.4

In the sample code the function `mycode(Base *p)`, calls `virt3` method as `p->virt3()`. Here how exactly the compiler know that virt3 is found in third slot of `vtable`? How do it compare and with what ?

Comment: For what compiler exactly do you want to get an answer?

Comment: What compiler? "vtables" are an implementation detail.

Answer (score 5):

When the compiler sees the definition of `Base` it decides the layout of its `vtable` according to some algorithm<sup>1</sup>, which is common to all its derived classes as far as methods inherited from `Base` are concerned (derived classes may add other `virtual` methods, but they are put into the `vtable` *after* the stuff inherited from `Base`).

Thus, when the compiler sees `p->virt3()`, it already knows that for any object that inherits from `Base` the pointer to the correct `virt3` is e.g. in the third slot of the `vtable` (because that's how it laid out the `vtable` of `Base` at the moment of its definition), so it can correctly generate the code for the virtual call.

---

Long story short (driving inspiration from @David Rodríguez's comment): it *knows* where it stays because he *decided* it before.

---

1. The standard do not mandate any particular algorithm (actually, it doesn't say anything about how the C++ ABI should be implenented), but there are several widespread C++ ABI specifications, notably the COM ABI on Windows and the Itanium ABI on Linux (and in general for gcc). Obviously, given the same class definition, the algorithm must give the same vtable layout every time, otherwise it would be impossible to link together different object modules.

Comment: +1 In other words: the compiler does not need to *know*, it *decides* the slot.

Comment: @David: good one, I'm adding something similar to the answer.

Comment: sorry not clear to me yet.  When I call p->virt3, how does the compiler (or linker?) know symbol virt3 is 3rd address ?

Comment: Because the compiler *decided* it when it defined the layout of the vtable associated with `Base`. Once he decides how is the layout of the vtable for each type (which happens after he read the class definition), it keeps it in memory to be able to generate the code for the virtual calls.

Comment: Then what about interoperability between two pieces of compiled C++ code? A possibly different compiler has then already decided which slot to choose. Isn't there a standard vtable layout as per calling convention? Or is this choice hidden inside a thiscall function that fetches the slot?

Comment: @Tinctorious: and in facts interoperability between C++ compilers is a nasty problem, because the standard do not even suggest anything about the C++ ABI. Still, more-or-less standard C++ ABIs do exist, on Windows the COM ABI is generally used, and AFAIK on Linux the Itanium C++ ABI has become the de-facto standard. They both mandate how the vtable must be laid out.

Answer (score 4):

[The layout of the vtable is specified by the Itanium C++ ABI](http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html#vtable), followed by many compilers including GCC. The compiler itself doesn't decide where the function pointers go (though I suppose it does decide to abide by the ABI!).

> The order of the virtual function pointers in a virtual table is the order of declaration of the corresponding member functions in the class.

([Example.](http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/cxx-abi/cxx-vtable-ex.html))

COM — used by Visual Studio — also emits vtable pointers in source order (though I can't find normative documentation to prove that).

Also, because the function name doesn't even exist *at runtime* (but a function pointer), the layout of the vtable at compile-time *doesn't really matter*. The function call translation works in just the same way that a normal function call translation works: the compiler is already mapping the function name to an address in its internal machinery. The only difference is that the mapping here is to a location in the vtable, rather than to the start of the actual function code.

This also addresses your concern about interoperability, to some extent.

Do remember, though, that this is all implementation machinery and C++ itself has no knowledge that virtual tables even exist.

Comment: How is this contrasting with what I said? The fact that the layout of the vtable is mandated by a public standard ABI or by some internal specification is not relevant with what I wrote into the answer.

Comment: @Matteo: I disagree, but I'm not sure enough to keep that phrasing in my answer now that you've spotted it ;-)

Comment: @Matteo: Actually, yea, I see it now.

Comment: Maybe now I understand, I think we read the question differently. I thought he asked "when the compiler finds a virtual call, how can it know in which slot is the correct function pointer?", and my answer is "it knows because he decided the layout of the vtable before"; instead, you understood "how the compiler decides how to lay out the vtable?" and you replied correctly "according to some specification" (which often is the Itanium C++ ABI).

Comment: The Itanium-ABI is a 64bit ABI for intel-ish processors. It is extensively used in Linux 64 (all compilers I know), but I don't think windows 7 64bit uses that ABI. If you move to 32bit platforms,   you will find more disparity, if you move out of the intel family of processors (including AMD) things change again.

Comment: @Matteo: Yea, you interpreted it correctly I think. I have now mangled my answer to half-address both. ;P

Comment: @David: [GCC follows the Itanium ABI exclusively regardless of platform, and has done since version 3.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html)

Comment: @Tomalak: and I added something of your interpretation to mine in a note. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: There was a Google Summer of Code proposal to implement the Microsoft C++ ABI in clang++, which seems to be a good indication of a disparity of ABIs and the fact that not everyone (at the very least Microsoft doesn't) follows the Itanium C++ ABI.

Comment: @David: I think that's because if you want to provide COM objects you *have* to follow the Microsoft C++ ABI.

Comment: @David: I never said "everyone" follows the Itanium C++ ABI. In fact, my answer explicitly says that MSVS follows COM interop instead.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler has a well defined algorithm for allocating the entries in the vtable so that the order of the entries will always be the same regardless of which translation unit is being processed. Internal to the compiler is a mapping between the function names and their location in the vtable so the compiler can do the correct transformation between function call and vtable index.

It is important, therefore, that changes to the definition of a class with virtual functions causes all source files that are dependent on the class to be recompiled, otherwise bad things could happen.